# When unit testing Call object is null whenever retrofit2 request is made

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, robolectric, retrofit2

Earlier my project was using Retrofit and everything seems working fine when I wrote unit testing. Now we upgraded to `Retrofit 2.0` using `compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0'`.
We are doing unit testing using Robolectric.
Here is the test we wrote for earlier Retrofit version.

```
        @Test
        public void testButton() throws Exception {
            button.setText("www.google.com");            
            button.performClick();    
            Mockito.verify(mockApiservice).getLinkDetails(requestArgumentCaptor.capture());
            assertThat(requestArgumentCaptor.getValue()).isEqualTo("www.google.com");         
            assertThat(button.getVisibility()).isEqualTo(View.GONE);
        }
```

Now when we upgraded to `Retrofit 2.0`,  and the `button` click real code changes to

```
 Call<MyPOJO> callObj = ApiService.getLinkDetails(encodedUrlString);
 callObj.enqueue(this);
```

The test is getting failed even though I changed the test code to -

```
            @Test
            public void testButton() throws Exception {
                button.setText("www.google.com");            
                button.performClick();         
                assertThat(button.getVisibility()).isEqualTo(View.GONE);
            }
```

The error which I'm getting now is -

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at callObj.enqueue(this);
```

which means that `callObj` is null
So 2 most important questions  -

1. Why am I getting the NPE in the real code?
2. How can I change my test code to make mock request to the API and get the mock response?

I searched everywhere but I didn't got any clue.
Please help me. Any input is greatly appreciated.

Logcat -

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.myapp.MyFragment.onButtonClick(MyFragment.java:428)
    at com.myapp.fragment.MyFragment.access$100(MyFragment.java:62)
    at com.myapp.fragment.MyFragment$3.onClick(MyFragment.java:148)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
    at com.myapp.MyFragmentTest.testButton(MyFragmentTest.java:122)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:251)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:188)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:54)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:152)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Comment: How about posting `getLinkDetails`?

Comment: This is getLinkDetails - `@GET("parseUrl")
    Call<MyPOJO> getLinkDetails(@Query("url") String link);`

Comment: And you pasted the actual error message you got? If not please do that rather than typing in something similar. So far I'm not seeing the problem.

Comment: Added the exact crash logs.

Answer (score 1):

I might have figured it out - it looks like you're calling `getLinkDetails` as a static method, but you need to do it like this:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
.baseUrl("https://url.com/")
.build();

ApiService service = retrofit.create(ApiService.class);
Call<MyPOJO> callObj = service.getLinkDetails(encodedUrlString);
callObj.enqueue(this);
```

You can reuse the `Retrofit` object and the service object, but not the `Call`.

Retrofit 2 documentation: http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Comment: Thanks for the response but it is not like what it seems. I'm using the same approach to make a request. I just didn't posted that code because that is not relevant. The app runs without any problem but it is the unit test where I face issues.

Comment: Hm, ok.  So line 428 is `callObj.enqueue(this);` ?

Comment: Yes exactly that's where I'm getting a NPE.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on.  You might isolate the service call stuff into a separate class (maybe a good idea anyway) and run an integration test on just that.  That would tell you if something is going on with the fragment or if it's something else.

Comment: How can you isolate the service call into a different class? You have to make a call somewhere in your fragment/activity.

Comment: Take everything to do with the Retrofit stuff and put it in a different class that doesn't extend Fragment or Activity.  Call it from your Fragment, and from an integration test.

Comment: I'm already doing that. The retrofit stuff is in a different class. I'm just making the request in the fragment.

Comment: Did you solve the issue? If not, do you use code with Retrofit.Builder() that @nasch presented? Also, it's better to place Retrofit Bulder part once in your application class.